# Change colours of disk space properties

Tags: windows-xp

Is is possible to change the colours of used and free disk space colours in drive properties?

So you know when it's game over.

[image]

Comment: Apparently it is because I've never seen those colors!  Mine appear as blue and pinkish-purple on all my machines 7,8,8.1

Comment: I believe it is controlled by the Windows Themes and there is no way to change them through some configuration options. Try to play around with "Windows color and Appearances" (should be available alongside themes) options to see if you can find anything related to it, at least in Win 7 I don't find anything that relates to it.